# Cant access Plesk, Error 'Can't open or create shared memory by shm.name, Permission denied'

Tags: ssh, plesk, ubuntu-server, plesk-onyx

i got a problem with Plesk (Ubuntu Webserver),- i cant access plesk.
I havent change anything before. The following error messages is shown:

Server Error
500
Plesk\Lock\Exception
Lock Manager error: '[LockManagerException] Can't open or create shared memory by shm.name: "/run/lock/lmlib/SharedLockManagerStorage0.2.4"; shm.start_size: "8388608"; error "Permission denied"'.

I cant try:
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003405193-Unable-to-open-Plesk-Lock-Manager-error-Can-t-open-or-create-shared-memory-by-shm-name

or

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002301654-Plesk-is-unavailable-after-upgrade-Can-t-open-or-create-shared-memory-by-shm-name

or

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000224773-Plesk-is-not-accessible-Can-t-open-or-create-shared-memory-by-shm-name

because i can currently only connect to Server via SSH when in rescue mode.
(Dont know why ... idea how to enable/check SSH, so i can connect in normal mode ??)

How can i fix the problem when the rescue mode is running?

Greetings,
Julian

Comment: if the system is booted in rescue mode you will not be able to run Plesk because recuse mode is limited and only some basic commands can be executed. For correct Plesk functionality system must be loaded is in normal mode.

Comment: The problem occurs also when server is in normal mode. Thats not the problem i meant.